# Does Tensorflow normalize input data by default?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, tensorflow, normalization

Does anyone know if Tensorflow normalizes input data by default?

I have grayscale images that values range from roughly 20000-28000. When I normalized the data something really odd happened. The network trained for a couple hundred iterations, was doing well in terms of making accurate predictions, but suddenly all predictions went to `NaN`. Of course it couldn't recover because TF can't optimize from `NaN`.

When I didn't normalize the data training went fine and converged.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show your model and the way you normalize?

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to normalize your input data for tensorflow?

Answer (score 3):

To answer the title question, tensorflow does not normalize input data by default. With regard to the NaNs, there's not much to say without seeing more details of what computation you are performing.